# How to check if an AWS STS access token is valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sts

I have a lambda function that uses AWS STS to generate temporary credentials and then sends the access token via HTTP to a Web API in an EC2 instance.

Is there a way to validate the received access token from the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling STS [GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) will tell you if the credentials are usable to make API calls, and it will identify the underlying AWS account and assumed role.

For example:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROAABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ:xyz",
    "Account": "123456781234",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456781234:assumed-role/somerole"
}
```

Notes about the [response object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html#API_GetCallerIdentity_ResponseElements):

- `Account` is the AWS account number of the account that owns/contains the calling entity
- `UserId` is the unique identifier of the calling entity. The exact value depends on the type of entity that is making the call.

Comment: The question is how to check whether a token received by the Web API was actualy generated by a legitemit user (lambda) or someone else (invalid access token)

Comment: What is the purpose of sending an access key on its own? What use do you intend to make of it (in the absence of secret key and session token)?

Comment: AWS security architecture assures you that any token generated by IAM represents a valid token, and that the given service that generated the token had permissions to do so. If you are concerned that some entity with elevated privileges generated a token, and that that token is not to be trusted, then you have a security configuration problem. You would need to check CloudWatch to see what entity generated the token, and revoke its permissions.

Comment: Anyone can generate a token that appears to be an AWS access key. In the absence of a record made by you of vended STS credentials, and without the corresponding secret key and session token, I don't see how you can validate an access key. Perhaps you could leverage CloudTrail to capture the creation of STS credentials?

Comment: Does the UserID refer to the temporary credentials or the ressource which requested them

Comment: Have added info about the [response object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html#API_GetCallerIdentity_ResponseElements) and pointer to documentation.

Answer (score -1):

AWS security architecture assures you that any token generated by IAM represents a valid token, and that the given service that generated the token had permissions to do so. If you are concerned that some entity with elevated privileges generated a token, and that that token is not to be trusted, then you have a security configuration problem. You would need to check CloudWatch to see what entity generated the token, and revoke its permissions.

As @jarmod suggests, if a given token works, then it is valid. That is all you can know about its validity.